# How to Isolate Bootstrap CSS to Avoid Conflicts with the default CSS style of a downloaded template

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I downloaded a template and I am customizing it based on my requirements. Everytime i add a bootstrap element it doesn't look as the expected result.

I have been searching for some solutions. I found this [one](https://formden.com/blog/isolate-bootstrap) as the best way to apply bootstrap only on the div I want. I added the `bootstrap-iso.css` [file](https://formden.com/static/assets/demos/bootstrap-iso/bootstrap-iso/bootstrap-iso.css) and I put my bootstrap code inside `<div class="bootstrap-iso">...</div>` 
but still not getting the correct result. It's still getting the default classes of my template not the bootstrap style

For example if I want  to add this searchable multiselect dropdown to my template. how can I insert it ? Thank you for your sugestion.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
     <select name="framework" id="framework" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" multiple>
      <option value="Laravel">Laravel</option>
      <option value="Symfony">Symfony</option>
      <option value="Codeigniter">Codeigniter</option>
     </select>
```

Comment: well you don't need to force things, you simply need to do them correctly .. we don't include a framework after the work is done. We do it at the beginning and then we adjust the CSS

Comment: Is that bootstrap-iso file supposed to stop your CSS intefering with the Bootstrap CSS?

Its not that specific so im sure either your CSS or the template CSS could be used instead. Does the template have its own stylesheet?

Comment: @AonghasM  yes the template has its own stylesheet and it's affecting every bootstrap element i add